# Updating foreign key values in bound ms access form fed with a view

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, view, dao

I am using an MS Access 2013 frontend which has a form that is bound to a DAO recordset read from a view. The view´s Primary key is set via VBA in Access like this:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ID ON View_X (ID) WITH PRIMARY"
```

The View is written on my SQL Server 2005 to which i connect via ODBC and is bound to the form via a DAO recordset like this:

```
Set rsM = DB.OpenRecordset("View_X")

Set Me.Recordset = rsM
```

Everythink works great but here is the Problem:

Assume the following SQL for the underlying View:

```
Select
  Tbl_Main.Quality_Note, Tbl_ProductGroup.PG_Description
From 
  Tbl_Main inner join Tbl_ProductGroup on 
  Tbl_Main.PG_ID = Tbl_ProductGroup.ID
```

Now I want to be able to have a Combobox in my Access form which is bound to the view-field PG_Description in my view and its list just contains the possible entries of PG_Description.

since my PK is defined i can actually edit the record in the form.
BUT the Problem I have is that the edit goes to the field Tbl_ProductGroup.PG_Description and changes the description of the entries (not good) but I just want it to edit the foreign key value Tbl_Main.PG_ID (ie. from 3 to 5)

Is there any way/trick I can accomplish this with bound forms in Access or do I have to update the record "manually" through SQL in VBA?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stolzenberg,

In your view_X add

```
Select
  Tbl_Main.Quality_Note,
  Tbl_ProductGroup.PG_Description,
  Tbl_Main.PG_ID
From Tbl_Main inner join Tbl_ProductGroup on Tbl_Main.PG_ID = Tbl_ProductGroup.ID
```

In your front-end form add a combobox bounding to the value PG_ID. As the Record/RowSource for the combobox add

```
SELECT
    Tbl_ProductGroup.ID,
    Tbl_ProductGroup.PG_Description
FROM Tbl_ProductGroup;
```

Finally set the combobox's column count to 2 and column width to 0;
this will hide the first key column and only show the product description.

let us know if you are stuck.

Comment: This worked like a charm!!

Thanks a lot for the quick reply :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the drop down is bound to the description column and not the foreign key column the only column it can update is the bound column.  You would need to use an unbound drop down and use an event to update the foreign key column.